# Interface method has interface argument but want to use class argument in the implementation

Tags: c#, interface

We have a set of components, and each of the components should be loaded their own way.

Consider the following:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    Type LoaderType {get;}
}

public class ComponentA: IComponent
{
    Type LoaderType => typeof(ComponentALoader);
}

public class ComponentB: IComponent
{
    Type LoaderType => typeof(ComponentBLoader);
}

public interface ILoader
{
    void Load(IComponent example);
}
```

Is there a way so that when I implement `ILoader` I can use the component type in the loaders instead of the interface (to avoid casting)?

Example:

```
public class ComponentALoader: ILoader
{
    void Load(ComponentA component) {}
}

public class ComponentBLoader: ILoader
{
    void Load(ComponentB component) {}
}
```

[EDIT: This is the current implementation which works, but requires a cast in each loader]:

```
public class ComponentALoader: ILoader
{
    void Load(IComponent component) 
    {
        // This is the cast that I was looking to avoid in favor of having the type in the method signature
        var compA = (ComponentA) component;
        doSomethingWithA();
    }
}

public class ComponentBLoader: ILoader
{
    void Load(IComponent component)
    {
        // This is the cast that I was looking to avoid in favor of having the type in the method signature
        var compB = (ComponentB) component;
        doSomethingWithB();
    }
}

public class ComponentBLoader: ILoader
{
    void Load(ComponentB component) {}
}
```

The entry point is something like:

```
List<IComponent> components = listOfComponents;
foreach (var component in components)
{
    // Retrieves the correct loader from a list of loaders 
    // based on the type property on the components
    var loader = getLoaderForComponent(component); 
    loader.Load(component);
}
```

EDIT:
1) It's worth noting that we're easily talking 100+ components with their associated loaders here, so a loader class with overloaded methods for each component is not something we'd like to go for

2) The list of loaders are given to the main loader using DI, I'm not entirely sure how we would do that with a generic interface. Maybe a `ILoader` interface to enable DI, and then `ILoader<T>` with the Load method. Not sure how I would map from a given `ILoader` to call a method on `ILoader<T>` though.

3) tl;dr We want to avoid that the main loader knows about the many types of components and loaders

4) The current solution works, maybe that cast in each loader is just necessary

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't really understand the goal from your question.

Comment: it sounds like you need a generic base class with which you can define the return type in the derived classes. That would circumvent the casting. But I am not sure whether I understood your question entirely

Comment: If the loader is concerned with the type of component then it's not generic, so an interface may not be the best approach.  You may be better making a loader class with overloaded load methods for different component types, but without knowing more it's just a fluffy guess.

Comment: I've added a little bit more at the bottom of the question. We have a large number of these components and their associated loaders so overloading is not a direction we want to go

Comment: Is the loader different for every component type?  If it is then add the loader into the component type, not a generic interface that uses it.

Comment: "The current solution works, maybe that cast in each loader is just necessary" could you clarify a little? I am still confused. I don't see any cast in your code, and the example that you posted does not compile.

Comment: I've added another edit (3rd code block) which shows the current implementation

Answer (score 1):

Lets see how good I understood your question. As said in the comments to avoid casting you could make your interface generic and define in the the implementing classes the generic type:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    Type LoaderType { get; }
}

public class ComponentA : IComponent
{
    public Type LoaderType => typeof(ComponentALoader);
}

public class ComponentB : IComponent
{
    public Type LoaderType => typeof(ComponentBLoader);
}

public interface ILoader<T> where T : IComponent // This restriction allows only types that implement the interface inside the load method
{
    void Load(T example);
}

public class ComponentALoader : ILoader<ComponentA>
{
    public void Load(ComponentA component) { }  
}

public class ComponentBLoader : ILoader<ComponentB>
{
    public void Load(ComponentB component) { }
}
```

This code compiles and you can use the type in the `Load` method instead of the interface

Comment: I went this route, but the main loader has a list of loaders injected based on the `ILoader` interface. Not sure how I can get a list of `ILoader<T>` without manually setting this up somewhere

Answer (score -1):

You must use [a generic class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)

```
public class Component<T> wher T:IComponent
{
    void Load(T component) {}
}
```

Comment: The question suggests that the OP wants something different for ComponentA and ComponentB, which is why this approach is not suitable.  It's unclear what their issue is, but to say "You must us a generic class" is incorrect.